# Bash: Import Command not found error Repl It

Tags: python, bash

I've been working on a project in Python using Repl it. I have some experience with programming but I am a beginner to github and right now I am stuck on an error. I tried many different things but don't understand what is causing the error. I need to type a set of commands to instruct the REPL environment to initialize the file directory as a git repository which would allow me to execute git commands within the directory after I finish the initialization. Once I import os in the shell, it gives me an error that bash: import: command not found. I am using Python. I was wondering if anyone had any solutions to help me fix this error. I would really appreciate it.

[Error being displayed in Repl IDE Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwIEI.jpg)

Comment: You seem to work on linux shell. Please first write `python` to fire python shell. Then add import statements

Comment: Please post the code or error into your question, not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repl.it's shell is a standard linux shell. Use the `python` command to open the interactive python prompt.